# Updating all rows that contain IDs not appearing in another table, in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm writing SQL code to update our product database from our supplier database.  To do this, I import the supplier database.  So far everything works.  Then, I run the following command to get a list of all the ID numbers that are available in our database, but are no longer listed in the supplier database:

```
SELECT id_number
FROM products
WHERE available IS true
EXCEPT
SELECT id_number
FROM supplier_db;
```

EXPLAIN message is "SetOp Except (cost=151027.48..154845.30 rows=454191 width=4)"

This runs fine, in about 1-2 seconds.  EXPLAIN gives this command a cost of 151027.48.  However, my end goal is to set the boolean `available` to false on every row that has an ID number appearing in this list.  So I use the following command:

```
UPDATE products
SET available = false
WHERE id_number IN (
    SELECT id_number
    FROM products
    WHERE available IS true
    EXCEPT
    SELECT id_number
    FROM supplier_db
);
```

EXPLAIN message is "Update on products (cost=224829.78..279637.52 rows=152540 width=640)"

However, the second command takes at least 15 minutes to run, which isn't really acceptable.  Is there any way to do this in Postgres that would significantly speed this process up?  Also, I may not be interpreting EXPLAIN results properly, but shouldn't the second command only take twice as long as the first one, considering the cost is only twice as much?

I tried using SELECT INTO to create a temporary table from the first SELECT query.  It did not change run time at all.  Also, `id_number` is indexed in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you run this query?

```
update products p
set available = false
where available = true
and not exists (select 1 from supplier_db sdb where sdb.id_number = p.id_number)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: EXPLAIN give me "Update on products p  (cost=20638.87..126959.03 rows=268901 width=614)"

I ran this on the production server, which admittedly runs things at a different speed that the development server, and it finished in 3 minutes.  (I couldn't run it on the development server because the development server had already been updated.) This is a huge improvement.  Thanks!

Comment: Also sometimes if you move to an IN() query with an outer join and a filter you can see even better performance improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like so, or its `not exists()` variation:

```
UPDATE products
SET available = false
WHERE available
AND id_number NOT IN (
    SELECT id_number
    FROM supplier_db
);
```

Comment: I did try that first, actually, however I cancelled it after it wouldn't finish after 10-15 minutes.  Using EXPLAIN on this command gives "Update on products  (cost=0.00..4368034538.73 rows=213664 width=608)".